# Converting evolutionary optimization problem from Excel to Python

Tags: optimization, python, solver

I've set up and successfully executed an evolutionary optimization in Excel, and now have a need to convert the problem to Python. `differential_evolution()` in the optimize package would seem to get me there, but doesn't appear to allow for the setting of a constraint such as `x1 < x2` (where `x1` and `x2` are elements of the decision variable vector).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you detail your evolutionary optimization ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could apply the following trick inside your objective function:

```
x1 = min(x[1],x[2])
x2 = max(x[1],x[2])
```

Now `x1 <= x2` automatically holds and you don't need the constraint. (Assuming you can live with `<=` instead of `<`).

Comment: Thanks much, Erwin! Follow-up question: do I only want this adjustment to hold within the function, or do I want to ensure the current decision vector maintains this "correction" in between objective function calls?

Comment: You can just do it inside the evaluation function. You also may need to repeat it when reporting the solution to the user.

Comment: Makes sense. Really clever solution; being relatively new to the study of optimization, I likely wouldn't have gotten there myself anytime soon!